# Godot bounce physics behaves unexpectedly after first bounce

Tags: game-physics, godot4

Godot 4.2.1 - there is no code, just the nodes.

This scene has just static bodies and rigid bodies. The RigidBody that falls (the ball) has a bounciness of 0.5 - round collision shape despite the square icon.

The edges of the field are simple collision shapes (lines). The white ramps at the bottom are rectangular collision shapes

The ball falls and bounces just fine, then just before its second bounce it behaves weirdly

What's going on?

[image: Godot physics]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
The two white ramps at the bottom was one static body with two collision shapes. Godot didn't like that.
I made one static body with a corresponding collision shape for each of the two ramps and now it works